# d3.js onmouseover in a for loop

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a bar plot in a for loop like:

```
            for (var dex=3;dex<=6;dex++){
        alert(dex);
        var depthBar =svgbin.selectAll("rect"+dex)
                       .data(bindata)
                       .enter()
                       .append("rect")
                       .attr("x", function(d) {
                            return xScale(d[0]);
                       })
                       .attr("y", function(d) {
                            d.push(dex)
                            return yupScale(accumDepth(d,3,dex));
                       })
                       .attr("width", function(d){
                            return binScale(d[1]);
                       })
                       .attr("height", function(d) {
                            return height-margin.bottom - yupScale(d[dex]);
                       })
                       .style("opacity", 0.8)
                       .attr("fill", barcolor[dex])
                       .attr("stroke","black")
                       .on("mouseover", function(d,dex) {
                           //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
                            var xPosition =parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + xLable.rangeBand();
                            var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + height*1.5;
                            var start = d[0];
                            var end = d[0] + d[1];
                            var posvale = start + ".." + end;

                           //Update the tooltip position and value
                           d3.select("#tooltip")
                             .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                             .style("top", yPosition + "px")                        
                             .select("#value")
                             .text(dex);
                           d3.select("#tooltip")
                             .select("#title")
                             .text("Depth:");
                           d3.select("#tooltip")
                             .select("#posvalue")
                             .text(posvale);

                           //Show the tooltip
                           d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
                        })
                       .on("mouseout", function() {
                            //Hide the tooltip
                            d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);  
                        }); 

    }
```

Four bar plot is drew by this for loop and I tried to add text to each bar through mouse event.

Everything works fine except the onmouseover part, I can't pass the dex as a argument into the function, why?

Comment: It's not clear at all to me what you're trying to do here. You certainly shouldn't need a for loop. Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/)?

Comment: the bindata is like this: [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8] ...]  I want to use the third, fourth, fifth and six element of each array to draw bar plot. That's way I need a for loop

Comment: No you don't. You just need to filter the data accordingly and then follow the usual D3 data binding pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `dex` parameter from the `mouseover` function. Simply using `dex` variable inside mouseover function will give you 7 always because the mouseover function will be called after the for loop iteration is completed and the value for `dex` variable in the scope will be 7 at that time.

So the possible fix would be to add dex value as an attribute in the `rect` and use it in the `mouseover` function.

```
var depthBar =svgbin.selectAll("rect"+dex)
       .data(bindata)
       .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("dex",dex) //Set dex as an attribute
       ...............
       ...............
       .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          var dex = d3.select(this).attr("dex"); //Get attr dex
          ...............
          ...............
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a misunderstanding of the difference between a variable in scope, and an argument definition for a function declaration.

the line:
`.on("mouseover", function(d,dex) {//..`
begins a function declaration for a function that will be executed on the mouseover event. You've arbitrarily named the second argument to that function `dex`, but that has nothing to do with the `var dex` you define in the for loop. And more so, it specifically overrides any reference the function might be able to hold to the `var dex`. But obviously the mouseover event is not going to execute your function and pass a value to it that will be useful as `dex`.

To solve, you should make a second variable, store the value of dex in it, and then you can either pass a function to `.on("mouseover",` that has no dex argument, but has closure over the new variable, or bind the new variable to the current function as the dex argument.

Comment: yes, that's my problem, how to pass dex to the mouseover function. If I simply wirte `".on("mouseover", function(d)"` and use dex in the function, it will be 7 forever, wwhich is the last value of the  loop